# Worksheet event inside Class Module

Tags: events, vba, excel

I've created a code for changing selected cell's color.
Usualy I put that code in Sheet1 VBA file, or any sheet that I'm using it on.

I want to put it into a Class Module file, so it can be easier to implement into another worksheet or excel file.

Is the Class Module even a good place for it? My whole idea is to have couple of that kind of events, and some easy way to turn them on and off, as well as migrate the code to another excel file.

What do you think would be the best approach to this?

The code goes like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Range("A1").Value = "yes") Then
        Dim iColor As Integer
        On Error Resume Next
        iColor = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
        iColor = 36
        Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        Target.FormatConditions.Add Type:=2, Formula1:=iInternational
        Target.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
    Else
        Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Putting this code in ThisWorkbook - `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` will also achieve what you want. There is no need for a class module for such a simple thing :)

Comment: The problem is that I want to generalize it for use in more than one excel files. I want it to be simply importable to any excel file. And via class module, I could it import into excel, and not have to copy/paste it in every excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddharth is spot on. You don't need a class module. To get around your problem, you could write code to update your workbook code, so that any given module in any give .bas file can be taken and copied into any object in your workbook.

So if you had Worksheet_Change code in myLibrary.bas, you could copy that out and place it in each Worksheet object in your workbook.

Here's a great place to get you started with that: [Working with Modules](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

Comment: So there isn't any automated way of doing that? I allways have to copy code from my .bas file or anywhere else to my worksheet object?

Comment: what i am suggesting is that you automate the coping of the code. You stick all your code that you want to store as a "library" into one workbook and write a function to select certain modules into a chosen workbook.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I haven't thought of that solution.